# How to initialize a vector with values in Java?

Tags: java, class, vector

I have an `abstract class Room` and 2 subclasses `Apartment` and `Parking Place`. I want to declare a Vector of `Rooms` and initialize it. This is my code, I can't figure out the correct syntax:

```
Vector<Room> rooms = new Vector<Room> {
        new Apartment(300),
        new ParkingPlace(200);
    };
```

It gives me error: `Not a statement`

Comment: Don't use `Vector` (use any other collection); there's double-brace initialization but to be honest just make the object first, then add the items to it. Lastly, a `ParkingPlace` being a `Room` is a little strange from a design standpoint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Double-brace initialization mentioned in Rogue's comment should look like this:

```java
Vector<Room> rooms = new Vector<>() {{
    add(new Apartment(300));
    add(new ParkingPlace(200));
}};
```

However, it may be better to use other way of initializing via `Arrays.asList` or `List.of` (since Java 9):

```java
Vector<Room> rooms = new Vector<>(Arrays.asList(
    new Apartment(300),
    new ParkingPlace(200)
));
```

Comment: Edit: Both `List#of` (immutable) and `Arrays#asList` (fixed-sized) may cause an issue if you don't do the wrapping in a new collection as well (as seen above). I'd still stay away from `Vector` though, that's very old API.

Comment: `List.of` is immutable, `Arrays.asList` is fixed size :)

Comment: Yes, `Vector` appeared yet in JDK 1.0, while `List`/`Arrays.asList` appeared in Java 1.2 along with the `Collections` framework

Comment: Maybe just repeating what others have said: **The second way is the clearly recommended one.**

Comment: Minor note: The double-brace initialization example has a syntax error: It should end with `}};` not `});`.

Comment: @andrewjames, fixed.  It happens all the time when the code is posted without actual compilation...

Answer (score 2):

You can create a Vector from the list.

```
Vector<Room> rooms = new Vector<>(List.of(new Apartment(300), new Apartment(200)));
```

But maybe you can use List instead of Vector

```
List<Room> rooms = List.of(new Apartment(300), new Apartment(200));
```